# Spring rest: upload file

Tags: java, file-upload, spring-boot, multipartform-data, spring-rest

I'm using this code to upload files in my java application using `resteasy` and it works perfectly.

```
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.providers.multipart.PartType;

public class FileUploadForm {

    public FileUploadForm() {
    }

    private byte[] data;

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @FormParam("uploadedFile")
    @PartType("application/octet-stream")
    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

Now I want to do the same thing by using spring boot and spring rest. 
I searched a lot about how to use `@FormParam` and `@PartType` in spring rest but I didn't find anything.

So how can I use this class to upload my files? What is the equivalent of `@PartType` and `@FormParam` in spring rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You want to write a code for file upload in spring rest its just simple u just need to use multipart file object as shown in the following code.**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public URL uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                                 @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

/***Here you will get following parameters***/
 System.out.println("file.getOriginalFilename() " + file.getOriginalFilename());
        System.out.println("file.getContentType()" + file.getContentType());
        System.out.println("file.getInputStream() " + file.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("file.toString() " + file.toString());
        System.out.println("file.getSize() " + file.getSize());
        System.out.println("name " + name);
        System.out.println("file.getBytes() " + file.getBytes());
        System.out.println("file.hashCode() " + file.hashCode());
        System.out.println("file.getClass() " + file.getClass());
        System.out.println("file.isEmpty() " + file.isEmpty());
/***
Bussiness logic
***/

}
```

Comment: Yes .from this parameters u will get all the possible information of that file object.